# How to publish and subscribe notification for multiple mobile platforms: Android, Iphone without polling

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, messaging, polling

I'm looking for the best way to develop a mobile application in a scenario, that basically users could subscribe to any topic, and when someone using a web app publish any message of that topic, the mobile users will be notified, instead of polling the server.

The client app needs to be run on multiple plattforms: iPhone, Android,..
The server app probably will be developed in PHP (Symfony2).

I've read that the options are:

- **(GCM)** Google Cloud Message - **Limitation**: works only with Android devices
- **(APN)** Apple Publish Notification Services - **Limitation**: Only with **IOS** uses **XMPP** Protocol to implement comunication between server/clients

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have got the right study with you , basically the push notification service is platform based so you have to go with **GCM** and **APN** on **IOS**.

This will give you more robust control with the device with the specific platforms.

> If you don't want to use the **notifications by these two** then you are
>   remaining with **polling from your server** and that would consume battery
>   and network bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Probably PHP? You may create a ASP.NET project using the [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) library and a database for all the channel/endpoint-ids. There is a [nice diagram](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/raw/master/Resources/PushSharp-Diagram.png) on it's functionality.

> PushSharp: A server-side library for sending Push Notifications to iOS (iPhone/iPad APNS), Android (C2DM and GCM - Google Cloud Message), Windows Phone, Windows 8, and Blackberry devices!